# Extract the PayPal sale id from a JSON response

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to extract the `Sale Id` for a PayPal transaction. I am using `PayPalAndroidSDK` and `PayPal_MPL`

So far I can retrieve the Payment Resource e.g. `PAY-...` using this:

```
 PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
 if (confirm != null) {
     try {
         Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString());

         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(confirm.toJSONObject().toString());

         paymentId = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
```

This returns:

```
{
    "client": {
        "environment": "live",
        "paypal_sdk_version": "2.8.4",
        "platform": "Android",
        "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
    },
    "response": {
        "create_time": "2015-01-03T19:51:53Z",
        "id": "PAY-...",
        "intent": "sale",
        "state": "approved"
    },
    "response_type": "payment"
}
```

I have tried the following to return the sale id (a 16 digit transaction number which is different to the above `id:PAY-`...), but it returns an error on:

```
paymentId = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getString("sale");
```

The PayPal REST API does show that the sale id is sent back in the `create a payment response` https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a JSON, so just do `jsonObj["response"]["id"]`
jsonObj["response"] gives you `{"create_time":"2015-01-03T19:51:53Z","id":"PAY-...","intent":"sale","state":"approved"}`
and `jsonObj["response"]["id"]` will give you the value of the id

Also I'm not sure why you're converting it from an object to a string and then back into an object. If it's not necessary, I'd refactor that code.